# SVM (probabilistic model) on Python3+ : Almost simmilar probability for all the cases

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, svm

I am using following code to run SVM (probabilistic model) on Python3+.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn import svm
from time import time

dum_data = pd.read_csv("dummy_variable_file.csv")
train_cols = dum_data.columns[5:]
target = dum_data.columns[4]

x = dum_data[train_cols]
y = dum_data[target]
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=442, train_size=0.70)

clf = svm.SVC(probability = True)
model = clf.fit(x_train,y_train)

output_predict_test     =   model.predict(x_test)
output_proba_test       =   model.predict_proba(x_test)
output_decision_test    =   model.decision_function(x_test)
```

My data set has 0.24mln rows and 38 dummy features (Have taken care of dummy trap). I am running this code on 70% of the base (train base). And applying it on 30% of base (test base). The code is running fine. NO ERROR there.
Now the problems that I am facing are as follows:

1. In *output_proba_test* the model is giving me almost same probabilities for all the 71k cases (either of two probabilities for prediction of "1": 0.856 or 0.144). My target variable has two values 1(purchase) & 0(Not purchase).
2. The process of model fit is taking more than 7hrs

If anybody can explain why this is happening? I have run the same code for Iris Data and it is giving me proper probability distribution. But for my data it is giving me hard time. Again, just to reiterate: Target variable: "0" & "1"; independent variable: 37 dummy variables with the values either "1" or "0". I have taken care of the dummy trap. In my overall dataset (0.24mln) number of 1s are 39k. In my train data set number of 1s are 26k out of 0.16mln total rows.

Comment: What is the overall proportion of 1 and 0 in the target variable (in the training set)?  Is it by chance 0.856 or 0,144?

Comment: @BrenBarn : My Bad, forgot to mention. In my overall dataset (0.24mln) number of 1s are 39k. In my train data set the same is 26k out of 0.16mln total rows. EDITED the same in the question.

Comment: Basically what I'm getting at is that getting repetitive predictions often indicates that your variables are not informative and the model is reduced to choosing based on simplistic stats like overall proportions.  How did you generate this dummy data?  Are the variables actually predictive of anything?

Comment: @BrenBarn :  For dummy data I have used pandas **get_dummies()** function.   The variable used are able to predict properly using Logistic Regression model (have tried Python & SAS). I am trying to develope SVM on the same data